Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' Error in flutter
I'm building an app for displaying images from a particular folder. However upon giving flutter run, I'm getting the below error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing /home/ram/projects/internship/STEMTEC/Flutter App 3/img-classification-prototype/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.img_classification_prototype">

    <!-- Required permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Optional for Android 11+ -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:label="image_classification"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:name="${applicationName}">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <!-- Flutter UI initialization theme -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <!-- Main activity intent filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Flutter engine meta-data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <!-- Query required for text processing plugin -->
    <queries>
this        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

The error came only after the addition of the following lines:
<!-- Required permissions -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
        <!-- Optional for Android 11+ -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

I tried viewing other questions having similar errors like this, but in my error, it mentions error in parsing the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Can anyone please help me understand the error, and help me address it? Thank you!
